# useEffect firing even when dependency array is not true or has not changed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I hava a simple component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { HousesType } from '@src/store';

export const Home = () => {
  const [houses, setHouses] = useState<HousesType[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Should it fire if properties has no length?');
  }, [houses.length])


  return <h1>Testing</h1>
}
```

For some reason when I render home, I get the console log even thou the `houses` array has no length

[image]

Comment: It will fire on first render, when the properties is initialized

Comment: It will fire once when the component is first rendered, then every time the length of the `properties` array _changes_. Whether the value of the dependency is `0` or something else is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks, how to to just render when the properties array has something in it?

Comment: Why do you _want_ to avoid that? What's the real context? You could maybe check `if (properties.length > 0)` inside the hook callback, but then it would skip if the array ever got emptied again (which might never happen and/or might be OK anyway). And the properties array _does_ have something in it: `0`.

Comment: I am making an API request on first render to fill that array and want to use this context only when I know the array has values

Comment: But that is the correct behaviour, I want exactly that, the array gets filled once the API call is successful and then it calls this context, if not or the array "gets empty" I would not want to run the context, so this is correct

Comment: Please, don't name your state setter as `setProps`. `props` are different from `state` & cannot be set inside the component. Such improper naming leads to further confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as someone said it will fire on first render, when the properties is initialized, but to avoid doing something whether properties.length isn't less than 1 then put your logic inside if condition :

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!properties?.length) {
      console.log('Should it fire if properties has no length?');
    }
  }, [properties.length])
```

Comment: Rather than `!properties?.length`, as I suggested above, I'd use `properties.length > 0`. `!` is too easily overlooked, and `properties` is never actually undefined so the optional access isn't needed.